# Xen Server expired cannot activate free (greyed out)

Tags: xen, activation

we have installed axenserver and my employee misssed to activate ist, now the 30 days period is over and we cannot activate the free version because the button is greyed out.

is there any chance to get it back to work again

Answer (score 1):

[Contact Citrix Support](http://www.citrix.co.uk/support/customer-service.html) as they provide support for Xen Server.